# How to pass DotNetObjectReference to JS DOM-event

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I am trying to utilise JS drag & drop in Blazor, which works fine in general but I want to set a custom drag image during the `ondragstart` event. In general my code looks like this:

```html
<div class="some-draggable-container"
     draggable="true"
     ondragstart="Element.dragStartHandler(event, '@(ImageSrcBase64)')" >
</div>
```

```js
Element.dragStartHandler = function(event, imgSrcBase64) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSrcBase64;
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

The problem occurring to me is that I need to call a .Net function after setting the drag image and I cannot find a way to pass the needed `DotNetObjectReference` through to the JS part.

Simply passing the newly created objectRef into the JS event call leads to an `Unexpected end of input` error.

```
ondragstart="Element.dragStartHandler(event, '@(ImageSrcBase64)', @(DotNetObjectReference.Create(this)))"
```

Also using the `JsonSerializer` does not do the trick. It surely does serialise the object and JS is able to deserialise it, but as expected the `DotNet.invokeMethod()` methods are not present.

```
ondragstart="Element.dragStartHandler(event, '@(ImageSrcBase64)', @(JsonSerializer.Serialize(DotNetObjectReference.Create(this))))"
```

Utilising the Blazor event and handling it fully in .Net does not offer the ability to set the drag image because the passed `DragEventArgs` are not fully compliant to the JS one.

Passing the event args through `IJSRuntime` into a JS function leads to errors because it's just not the same thing as the native JS event, so at least the `setDragImage()` Method is missing.

Is there any way to make this work? I don't want to juggle around with JS-to-static-.Net calls and guids or that kind of workaround.

---

**Edit**
As [@MisterMagoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo) mentioned in a now deleted comment: It would be a sufficient way to pass the `DotNetObjectReference` during the first cycle of `OnAfterRender` to the JS part as well as a static guid and reference it later if needed.

The problem with that is that in my case the list can easily be ~50-100 Entries long and I don't know how this would impact performance an memory. So in small cases this would be fine but in my case probably not.

---

**Edit**
So to clarify the reason of the way I choose to solve this problem in the first place: I do know that I could solve this problem purely in Blazor by simply creating an image that follows the cursor. But through JS there is an already existing way to set the drag image that is handled by the Browser itself in terms of image positioning and movement. So I wanted to go the most performance efficient route rather then fully utilising Blazor because we have a narrow performance window for our application.

Comment: This is a very complex way to solve a situation that born as a bad move because this is not the way to do the things. I will suggest you continue learning and catch the programming pattern for Blazor adding your own methods in ajax to get working a more deep layer in C# through JSON

Comment: @LeandroBardelli If you are familiar with this problem, or can give feasible suggestions, I think this should also be a good answer.

Comment: @IvanYang I don't tried to offend, and for real my comment is not related to the question, I just think that (for me, in my humble experience) this will be more easy and quick to refactor in a good pattern that try to resolve this problem

Comment: When I get to this situations, always try to see if erasing and begin again can solve the path I took in first place

Comment: Sorry, my english sometimes sounds very hard. Definitely I tried to suggest, not offend

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I surely know there is a way to solve this purely with Blazor code but there are already performance issues in the application so I thought it is more sufficient to use Browser functionality then to reinvent the wheel. (I should mention that in the question I quess...)

Comment: @xevoryn Does the below answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

this is just bad psuedo code i'm writing in notepad from memory and the code does point in a loop, but it should give you an idea of how to call into javascript and then send the data back to c#

in a js file:

```
window.myBlazor = {
    doSomething: function(cSharpObjectReference, val1, val2) {
    // some js stuff happens
    cSharpObjectReference.Notify(someData);
}
```

in a cs file:

```
public static class MyInterops
{
private static readonly string _BaseObjectContainer = "myBlazor";
        public static async Task DoSomethingCs(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, ObjectJavaScriptShouldUse cSharp, MyModel model)
        {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync($"{_BaseObjectContainer}.doSomething", DotNetObjectReference.Create(cSharp), model.Val1, model.Val2);
        }
}


public class ObjectJavaScriptShouldUse 
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;
    [JSInvokable]
    public async ValueTask Notify(MouseEvent eventArgs)
    {
       await MyInterops.DoSomethingCs(_jsRuntime, this, eventArgs); //i accidentally pointed these calls in recursion, but you get the idea
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going but your answer does target JS interop in general not my specific case. Again: The problem is that I am not able to pass the JS event arguments of the `ondragstart` event to JS (I need to pass this right away because on every other way the functionality gets lost) while also passing a DotNetObjectReference in the same call (that is because there are many objects referencing the same function).

Comment: i would just let the html/js handle the dragging in the ui and hook into the onDragEnd event and send the final position to your code. your original post isnt fully clear on what you're trying to achieve other than passing data back and forth between js and cs. you would have to do it the way i suggested, but if you try to pass whole objects from js you will get serialization errors so only pass the data that matters and reconstruct in js or cs